# Control draggable movement in jQuery

Tags: jquery, draggable, positioning

how can I control de movement of a draggable in jquery?

I need to do something similar to the "snap to grid" where the draggable moves every "x" and "y" pixels

I can't use "grid: [x, y]" (2D) because I need to make the drag on an isometric grid (3D) (I will develop the grid later, I first need to controll the drag)

for example: when I start the dragging, the draggable shouldn't move, it has to snap to another position when the "x" and "y" are under certain conditions

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I've found what I was looking for!

[in this link](http://www.themaninblue.com/experiment/Cubescape/new.php) was the piece of code that I needed

the code is this:

//inside drag: function(event, ui)

```
    var offset = $(this).parent().offset();
    var GRID_SPACING = 10;
    var SELECTION_OFFSET_X = 10;
    var SELECTION_OFFSET_Y = 3;            

    if (parseInt(event.clientX / GRID_SPACING) % 2 == 0)
    {
        var row = Math.floor((event.clientY - offset.top) / GRID_SPACING) + Math.floor(event.clientX / (2 * GRID_SPACING));
        var col = -Math.floor((event.clientY - offset.top) / GRID_SPACING) + Math.floor((event.clientX + GRID_SPACING) / (2 * GRID_SPACING));
    }
    else
    {
        var row = Math.floor((event.clientY + GRID_SPACING / 2 - offset.top) / GRID_SPACING) + Math.floor(event.clientX / (2 * GRID_SPACING));
        var col = -Math.floor((event.clientY + GRID_SPACING / 2 - offset.top) / GRID_SPACING) + Math.floor((event.clientX + GRID_SPACING) / (2 * GRID_SPACING));
    }

    var new_x = row * GRID_SPACING + col * GRID_SPACING - SELECTION_OFFSET_X;
    var new_y = (row * (GRID_SPACING / 2)) - (col * (GRID_SPACING / 2));                     

    if(event.clientX == new_x + GRID_SPACING * 2)
    {
        ui.position.left = new_x;
        new_x = event.clientX;
    }

    if(event.clientY == new_y + GRID_SPACING)
    {
        ui.position.top = new_y;
        new_y = event.clientY;
    }                    

    ui.position.left = new_x;
    ui.position.top = new_y;
```

I changed some of the constants to adjust to my grid...

Answer (score 1):

Try using the options inherent in the .draggable() function at http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

basically it says you need to have the `snap` option set to `true` like this:

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({ snap: true, snapMode:'outer', snapTolerance:40 });
```

snapMode "...determines which edges of snap elements the draggable will snap to. Ignored if snap is false. Possible values: 'inner', 'outer', 'both'."
And snapTolerance is "...The distance in pixels from the snap element edges at which snapping should occur."

Or try using the `grid` option.  This is created to do exactly what you want:
"...Grid snaps the dragging helper to a grid, every x and y pixels. Array values: [x, y]
Code examples":

Initialize a draggable with the grid option specified.

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({ grid: [50, 20] });
```

Get or set the grid option, after init.

```
//getter
var grid = $( ".selector" ).draggable( "option", "grid" );
//setter
$( ".selector" ).draggable( "option", "grid", [50, 20] );
```

Hopefully this helps you.

Comment: attaching an image to clarify: [see image](http://img215.imageshack.us/img215/3756/isogrid.png)

if a use the grid option in image "A" I can snap to the green tiles, but not the blue one. if I set a smaller grid the result is that I can snap to the blue tile, but also to the ones in red, which aren't a valid tile, see image "B"

Comment: Maybe you could start your code in jsFiddle.net and paste the link back here for me to look at and edit...